# Adding classes in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I'm new to Xcode and have a set of instructions for a library that I need to import.
The documentations says:

> Please add X.h and X.m into project by clicking Classes, Add and
>   Existing Files.

Q: Where is the "Classes" menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "classes" menu per-say.

You want to right click(or CMD + Click) on the folder containing your actual project visible in the left pane of XCode 4(The Project Navigator, or CMD + 1) and add existing files.

Alternatively, you can also go through Files -> Add Files to "Project". Then select your files.

Regardless of how you do it, make sure to check the box that says "Copy item's into destination groups folder. (If Needed)"

Comment: Thank you very much Karoly!  I'm currently watching the Lynda.com essential training, but it was done with Xcode 3.1 and it looks like version 4 had quite a few changes.